# write a simple shell script,which will scan the ports for protocols: FTP,SSH,SMTP,HTTP for the first 10 hosts in the network

Tags: ssh, ftp, smtp, ports

I need help writing a simple shell script,which will scan the ports for protocols: FTP,SSH,SMTP,HTTP for the first 10 hosts in the network .

```
#Select port range
$portrange = 20,21,22,25,80
#Open connection for each port from the range
Foreach ($p in $portrange)
{
$Socket = New-Object Net.Sockets.TcpClient      
$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
#Connect on the given port
$Socket.Connect("10.59.80.64/24")
#Determine if the connection is established
if ($Socket.Connected) {
Write-Host "Outbound port $p is open." -ForegroundColor Yellow
$Socket.Close()
}
else {
Write-Host "Outbound port $p is closed or filtered."}
} #end foreach
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This script will scan the ports and save scan information in file scanport.out.
I use the default port for FTP (21), SSH (22), STMP (25) and HTTP (80).

```
> scanport.out #creates blank file

for i in {0..9} #scan 10 first hosts
do
    nc -v -z 192.168.1.$i 21 >> scanport.out 2>&1 #ftp
    nc -v -z 192.168.1.$i 22 >> scanport.out 2>&1 #ssh
    nc -v -z 192.168.1.$i 25 >> scanport.out 2>&1 #smtp
    nc -v -z 192.168.1.$i 80 >> scanport.out 2>&1 #http
done
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Hi luis, this is my code but i'm trying to add more hosts, 

#Select port range
$portrange = 20,21,22,25,80
#Open connection for each port from the range
Foreach ($p in $portrange)
{
$Socket = New-Object Net.Sockets.TcpClient      
$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
#Connect on the given port
$Socket.Connect("10.59.80.64/24")
#Determine if the connection is established
if ($Socket.Connected) {
Write-Host "Outbound port $p is open." -ForegroundColor Yellow
$Socket.Close()
}
else {
Write-Host "Outbound port $p is closed or filtered."}
} #end foreach

Comment: Oh sorry I thought you were using shell linux but I see it's powershell. In this case I will answer.

Answer (score 0):

This script will scan ports with PowerShell.

```
$net="10.67.198"
$range=210..220
#Select port range
$portrange = 20,21,22,25,80

foreach ($r in $range) {

    $ip="{0}.{1}" -F $net,$r
    write-host $ip

    #Open connection for each port from the range
    Foreach ($p in $portrange) {

        $Socket = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient 

        $ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue' 

        #Connect on the given port
        $Socket.Connect($ip, $p)

        $ErrorActionPreference = 'Continue'

        #Determine if the connection is established 
        if ($Socket.Connected)
        { 
            Write-Host "Outbound port $p is open." -ForegroundColor Yellow 
            $Socket.Close()
        } 
        else {
            Write-Host "Outbound port $p is closed or filtered."
        }

        $Socket = $null

    }
    #end foreach

}
```